# passing Variable Issues in Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

In my application I used ajax to send mails.There i pass the phone number as 111-111-1111 that may or maynot correcting working client's server.
This is my ajax code

```
var va = $("#txtname").val();
var va1 = $("#txtphone").val();
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "http://localhost/houndzabout/process.php/"+va+"/"+va1,
    success: function(msg) {
        if(msg == 0) {
            alert("Your Request Is Send!");
        } else {
            alert("Your Request Is Failed!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's is your question?

Comment: what's the problem you are facing, please elaborate your question.

Comment: @Kichu User, did any of the answers solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameters like ;

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/houndzabout/process.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {name : $("#txtname").val(), phone: $("#txtphone").val()},
  success: function(msg){
    if(msg == 0)
    {
      alert("Your Request Is Send!");
    } else {
      alert("Your Request Is Failed!");
    }
  }
});
```

In process.php file, get params like ;

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
   $name = $_POST['name'];
}

if(isset($_POST['phone']))
{
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "POST" as the type, yet you are passing variables using the GET method (in the url).  You need to set up a data JSON object and pass the data that way.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/houndzabout/process.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    va: $("#txtname").val(), 
    va1: $("#txtphone").val()
  },
  success: function(msg){
    if(msg == 0)
    {
      alert("Your Request Is Send!");
    } else {
      alert("Your Request Is Failed!");
    }
  }
});
```